# How can I combine these two regex expression to one?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to combine two patterns into 1:

```
string pattern_1 = @"smoke-test-app-[0-9A-Fa-f\-]{36}";
string pattern_2 = @"SMOKES-[0-9]-APP-[0-9A-Fa-f\-]{16}";
```

Test string for `pattern_1`: `smoke-test-app-f47980d7-b3e5-49eb-99b6-d7413e16a0bc`

Test string for `pattern_2`: `SMOKES-2-APP-a9a8f59dd3c74046`

Comment: Try using an alternation `(?:smoke-test-app-[0-9A-Fa-f\-]{36}|SMOKES-[0-9]-APP-[0-9A-Fa-f\-]{16})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One key things to understand here is the possibility to use insensitive case, since you have the same word in both uppercase and lowercase. As for the rest, it's basic OR operaiton.

```
/smoke(s?)-(test|\d{1})-app-([0-9A-Fa-f\-]{36}|[0-9A-Fa-f\-]{16})/gmi
```

Note that the `i` flag is important here.

I've created a [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/R71oU5/1) if you wish to test more cases

**P.S.** 
I did this out of pure love for regexes, but we would have appreciated if you tried yourself first.